# Climbing stairs

Tags: exercise

Is there a negative side to climbing stairs as an exercise? It's a very practical and quick exercise to get my heart pumping strongly every day. (30 floors) I use the lift to come down to avoid excessive wear on joints.

Comment: As long as your joints agree with you and you're not over-exerting yourself, you should be fine. BTW, **that's an awesome heart-pumping exercise.**

Answer (score 4):

The only caveat I would offer, being a bit of a stairclimber myself, is to make sure your form is good, knees over your feet at all times, a good amount of your foot on the stair tread, that sort of thing. And at least trail one hand along the banister so you can grab it for support as necessary. Falling on stairs is no picnic and it's easy, especially when you start getting tired, to miss a step or only land on it with your toes.  I have a crooked little finger on one of my hands as the result of a fall back in college which dislocated a joint.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more about good form & stairs? If you feel like writing a whole answer, I may post it as a question.

Answer (score 3):

Provided you have no underlying conditions that would make exercise harmful for you, I don't know why you'd have any problems. Perhaps just ensure you walk around for a couple of minutes before you tackle the 30 floors.

As a bonus, in the event of a fire or other emergency you'll know those things like the back of your hand.

Comment: Yes, instead of walking around, I stop every 3 floors then wait 15-30 seconds to let my heartbeat slow down. I would recommend it to anybody who wants a gradual way of getting at least some exercise, without overdoing it. Actually I'm recovering from a meniscus surgery, but climbing stairs actually seems to help. Good point about fire or earthquakes ...but I might find myself on the roof instead of the street.

Answer (score 0):

It is not harmful per se, but it is not the optimal way of training. It is not training all the muscle fibers, and it is not preparing your body at all planes. You are not doing any lateral movements for example. Which should be incorporated for a better overall exercise.